# how to connect sockets using static ip java

Tags: java, sockets, ip

I want to know if I can Connect Java sockets using a static IP Address. I've recently bought static IP from my ISP and I want to connect a Client Program that use Java socket with my laptop (as a server). I've tried it before in a closed network and it work normally, but when I've tried it with distributed network it doesn't work. Here is a piece of my code

---

Server :

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5432);    
Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
```

Client :

```
Socket socket = new Socket(IP,5432);
```

The problem is what should the IP be ? 
The Static IP or the IPV4 ?

Comment: If you're in the same network you should just use the local IP but if you are trying from a different network  you should use your Routers Public IP and might need to port forward to your local machine.

Comment: @3kings I actually need to connect from different network , so what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the static IP you bought is publicly routable (i.e. not 10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x-172.31.x.x or 192.168.x.x) and that your routers / firewalls allow access to this IP from the public Internet, you should be able to access that IP from anywhere.

Comment: Should I modify any thing in the router settings ?

Comment: At a minimum, the routers should be configured to allow external traffic to reach your static IP at TCP port 5432 and disallow any other port.  That's assuming that you only want that port accessible.

Comment: And how can I do this ? Can you please help me !

Comment: Thanks I've just edit some settings and it really works